# jumping between menus in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frames

I have been developing command line programs in Java for a while now and am investigating ways to implement a GUI solution.  I am new to this so any help would be extremely helpful.  Thanks in advance.
I have recently asked another question about buttons but I now have another.

I have been learning from a book how to use the action listener to perform actions based on buttons.  However, in the book, the buttons simply called a method which produced a text output.

I need a way to allow the user to press a button which takes him/her to a new window with different buttons/options and if the user wants they can press another button to return to the previous window.  If someone could show me a skeleton solution with explanation for my example below:

user is presented with two buttons, "library menu" and "account menu"
if the user presses "library menu" they are taken to a window with options to add book, delete book, etc with a final button to return back to the home screen.
If the user presses "Accounts menu" they are presented with a new window/menu with buttons to add, delete, rename, etc and again a final button to return back to the home screen/main menu.

With the command line this was simple because choosing library would call a method in the library class.  That method would have a switch case which called different methods based on the users input and when the user entered 'e' for example the switch case had an option to return out of the method i.e. a return statement took the user back to the method that initially called it (in the home screen).

I am extremely grateful for any help/advice/information on this!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not recommend to present multiple windows or frames to the user, it becomes quickly confusing and annoying.

Generally, if you want to switch the view you should use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which would allow you to change what's on the users main display.

You could also use a [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) which would allow the user to move between different views as they like

Answer (score 1):

You could make a JPanel for every "window", and switch that in a JFrame. To have the same design, which can be altered in future, you need some kind of modeling: a generation step for adding a button etc.

Working with Action-s (AbstractAction) helps decoupling, separating all in Model-View-Controller.

The real app will probably be one main JFrame, maybe calling some JFrames, certainly the ideas proposed by @MadProgrammer. Your JPanels can be plugged in, whether in a JTabbedPane, JInternalFrame or whatever.

Make MVC-Classes providing a JPanel, managing the Actions.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware of the actionListener, you probably knew how to create a JFrame, and it seems that your logic is OK. Correct me if I'm wrong, you just need a skeleton of an ActionListener?
For the mouseListener of your button, this should probably work just fine:

```
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit"); // Creating the button

btnExit.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() { // Adding a mouseListener to your component
    // Mouse is pressed in this component
    @Override
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
        yourFrame.dispose() // Closes your JFrame
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create all windos (new Window) first and only show them on button click, that way you wont have many instances of the same window.

```
public MainWindow extends JFrame
{
    private LibraryWindow libWin;
    private AccountsWindow accWin;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        libWin = new LibraryWindow();
        libWin.setParent(this);
        accWin = new AccountsWindow();
        accWin.setParent(this);

        ...

        this.show();
    }

    btnLib.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() { // Adding a mouseListener to your component
    // Mouse is pressed in this component
    @Override
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){
        libWin.show(); //shows your window on top of the main window

        //if you want to switch windows you can hide the parent
        this.hide();
    }
});


public LibraryWindow extends JFrame
{


    public LibraryWindow()
    {
        //create/design the window

        ...

        //don't show the window, the main window will do that
    }

    btnExit.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() { // Adding a mouseListener to your component
    // Mouse is pressed in this component
    @Override
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ){

        //if you want to switch windows you can show the parent
        this.parent.show();

        this.hide(); //only hide the window in order to reuse it
        //restore the window to its initial state
    }
});
```